# Android - How to pass Fragment object as an Activity object

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a method that accepts Activity as object. The method further starts new activities using this Activity object based on certain business logic.
But I need to use this method from inside of a Fragment.

How can I convert a fragment object to an Activity object.

Comment: Rather than casting fragments to activities (which is considered bad practice) you could create a Util Object and expose your method in there, that way it can be called from anywhere its needed

Comment: i can't think of _any_ reason why you should be passing an activity around

Comment: This function is in a different module, and is in a non UI class where they are accepting only Activity objects. I now need to call this function from within my Fragment

Comment: what language are you using ?

Comment: Kotlin. I wanted to if using `activity as Activity` would work. I know it is not a good practise, so are there any other options available?

Comment: I dont want to initiate a function in my parent fragment. There is a (non UI) static class in a different module, that basically wants to start activities using this activity object reference being passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is worth writing as an answer/explanation

You're asking :

> How can I convert a fragment object to an Activity object.

Well, you can't really convert these, but you can get the activity your fragment is attached to, by calling:

```
requireActivity()
```

what it does internally:

```
@NonNull
public final FragmentActivity requireActivity() {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to an activity.");
    }
    return activity;
}
```

---

You also said you were considering using:

```
activity as Activity
```

activity here is actually a getter, so it calls `getActivity()` which is nullable, while you could cast it, i suppose, it would be safer to do:

```
activity?.let{ instance ->
//use instance
}
```

---

if you have an instance of a fragment available, let's say:

```
val foo : Fragment
```

you can still just use `foo.requireActivity()` or `foo.activity`